# Alpine js getting the error can't find store and the object inside the store

Tags: javascript, arrays, styling, alpine.js

I'm trying to make a for loop inside the Alpine component from a store, but I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')". Even though I'm doing the for loop inside the template tag and passing the values correctly I think. What might be the problem ? Or do I need the import the store inside the html file ?

**https://codesandbox.io/p/github/filippovichaalexander/Alpine-Vesna/main?workspaceId=fabc2c3d-ba2a-4510-8a92-583144ef1275&file=%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A24%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A7%2C%22startColumn%22%3A24%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A7%7D%5D**

```js
// index.html
<div class="content__mid" x-data="">
  <template x-for="item in $store.products.items" :key="item.id">
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.title"></p>
  </template>
</div>

//script.js

import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
 
Alpine.store('products', {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Aspirin',
      country: 'USA',
      manufacturer: 'Bangladesh',
      price: '120',
      validDate: '02.10.2024'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Aspirin',
      country: 'Italy',
      manufacturer: 'Bangladesh',
      price: '120',
      validDate: '02.10.2024'
    }
  ]
})
 
Alpine.start()
```

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I haven't heard of Alpine before, from looking at their docs it doesn't look like the highest quality library. You might get a faster answer in their Discord.

Comment: It's working for me. How do you include `script.js` in the HTML file? Which bundler/webserver do you use?

Comment: I'm include it at the top of the header html tag as <script type=”module” src="./script.js"></script>. And I'm opening the html file it with liveserver. The rest of the static code is visualized, but the one that goes from script.js doesn't. https://codesandbox.io/p/github/filippovichaalexander/Alpine-Vesna/main?workspaceId=fabc2c3d-ba2a-4510-8a92-583144ef1275&file=%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A24%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A7%2C%22startColumn%22%3A24%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A7%7D%5D

Comment: I've updated the code with the project link